# Joomfish for Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomfish

I installed Jomfish component in Joomla 2.5 and successfully installed the core laguage plugin for Italian language.

But while installing Joomfish Translate for Italian laguage, I am getting an error - "Aborting language installation: Another extension is already using directory"

Please comment it.

Comment: what do you mean by installing Joomfish Translate for Italian laguage?

Comment: I refer this video tutorial - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6bKh9X2Q7fI

Step 1 : Installing Joomfish

Step 2 : Installing language pack from Joomla extension - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/languages/translations-for-joomla/286

Step 3 : Installing Joomfish Translator - http://www.joomfish.net/en/downloads/joomfish-translations

If I neglect the step 2, while doing step 3, it show error - core pack is missing. Once done step 2, while doing step 3, it show error - another extension already running". 

Please help me to fix it.